# Is it possible to receive notifications about new MS Outlook messages in Teams?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-teams, instant-messaging

Is there any Outlook (I use version 2016) plug-in or something to achieve that? I browsed for solution, but to no avail. After all these two pieces of software come from the same company and it is logical to expect them to work in concert.

I know that it works the other way around, user may choose to receive e-mail message about missed Teams' conversations, but this is not what I am interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my experience, maybe you could try to create a flow with Outlook and teams via Power Automate like below, you could design it for your need(log in your office.com> search for power automate app>create new auto folow):

[image]

So that there would be a notification post on your Teams channel when a new message arrived your Outlook.
[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!